# adding attachment from form while sending mail from gmail via php

Tags: php, gmail, bulk-mail

i am trying to add atatchment while sending mail from gmail using php. But it shows error...it says `Could not access file: hai.jpg`

follwing is the code i use

**gmail.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PHPMailer - GMail SMTP test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../Mail/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = "name@gmail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password   = "passwrd";
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['from'], $_POST['from_name']);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['from'],$_POST['from_name']);
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['to'],$_POST['to_name']);
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST['message']);
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
$mail->AddAttachment($_POST['attachment'],'application/octet-stream');
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="gmail.php" method="POST">
    <div>
        From Name:<input type="text" name="from_name" />
        From:<input type="text" name="from" />

    </div>
    <div>
        To Name:<input type="text" name="to_name" />
        To:<input type="text" name="to" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Message:<textarea  name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        Attachment:<input type="file" name="attachment" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value ="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I dont know what if i am doing the right way here.Can anyone please guide me through this?

Comment: The best way would be to upload the file and link it in the mail.

Comment: You missed the enctype attribute in your form element. For example, <form action="gmail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: is $_POST['attachment'] a file you're uploading? if so, then that's NOT how php handles file uploads.

Comment: Please tell me how to do that...!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've notice the absence of two itens in your code:

1. The use of the php [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) variable, which stores information about the uploaded files
2. The use of [enctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.2) attribute in your form element, which is required to upload files along with the form.

So, your code must treat this two itens.

Your form will look like this:

```
<form action="gmail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        From Name:<input type="text" name="from_name" />
        From:<input type="text" name="from" />

    </div>
    <div>
        To Name:<input type="text" name="to_name" />
        To:<input type="text" name="to" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Message:<textarea  name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        Attachment:<input type="file" name="attachment" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value ="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And your code may treat the `$_FILES` variable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PHPMailer - GMail SMTP test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 //access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../Mail/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = "name@gmail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password   = "passwrd";
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['from'], $_POST['from_name']);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['from'],$_POST['from_name']);
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['to'],$_POST['to_name']);
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST['message']);
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attachs the file only if it was uploaded by http post
if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
  $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name'], 'base64',$_FILES['attachment']['type']);
}
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With this code attachment is going but not the one that I selected.. It goes as `application/octect-stream.dat`

Comment: Right. Do you mind to pass a link to the documentation of phpmailer?

Answer (score 0):

Its not quite that straight forward uploading a file from the client browser to the server.

[Here's a simple tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)